# How do I programmatically find the OS X volume name for a mount point?

Tags: macos, cocoa, go, filesystems

I'm writing a fuse file system, and using the [`volname` mount option](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options#volname) supported by osxfuse to set the volume name. This works—I can see the correct name in the Finder when I view the folder containing the mount point.

However, I would like to write a test for the functionality to make sure I don't screw it up at some point in the future. How can I get the volume name for the mount programmatically in my test? I tried `statfs(2)`, but `statfs::f_mntfromname` contains the distinct "file system name", as displayed in the output of `mount`.

I'm writing this in Go, so am looking for a specific syscall that I can call, not e.g. a Cocoa library function. But if you know how to do it in Cocoa that would still be a useful lead.

Comment: I haven't tested this so this is a comment, but you could probably do this with cgo and Core Foundation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLEnumeratorRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLEnumeratorCreateForMountedVolumes https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Volume_Property_Keys

Comment: Thanks, I'll try writing a small C program to extract `kCFURLVolumeNameKey`, run it through `dtruss`, and see what syscalls it's making.

Comment: Why not use cgo and just use the CF APIs directly? :S

Comment: cgo causes slower build times, issues with dynamic linking, etc. Better to not use it if possible, but of course it's an option.